# build latest sources with a changeset in tfs

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I want to get the changeset of last good build of a given build definition and then build for that changeset. Is there any way to achieve this by modifying the defaultTemplate? Maybe I can use an In Argument to pass the build definition name to the build process template.
Any help/direction/insight is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by "Latest Sources plus a Changeset", Latest Sources by definition includes *all* changesets.

Answer (score 0):

In the default template there's an argument "GetVersion" under advanced you can specify a changeset to build.

According to the description this just overrides the iBuildDetail.SourceGetVersion.